# Is this relationship between spectral radius and singular values false?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I found the following relationship $\max_{i} \sigma_i \le \rho(A)$, where $A$ is a matrix. 
But somehow I do not trust this relation, I'd rather guess that the converse is true, but I do not know.

Comment: I believe the reverse inequality is true.

Comment: sorry, are you sure or do you just guess?

Comment: oh it is definitely true, easy to prove, take an unit norm eigenvector and bound the norm of Ax above by spectral radius, then note max singular value is by definition larger (supremum is over all vectors, not just eigenvectos)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given any matrix norm $||\cdot||$, it can be proved that the spectral radius of a matrix $A$ is always less or equal than the norm of $A$, i.e. $\rho(A) \le ||A||$. Now the expression $\max_i \sigma_i$ is simply the induced $2$-norm of $A$. This proves that the reverse inequality from the one you show is true.

Answer (score 4):

How about $A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$? Spectral radius is $1$, but the maximum singular value is larger than $1$. It's true for symmetric matrices, however.